# Error al resolver variables

Tags: java, variables

Estoy creando mi primer "programa" en java. Acabo de empezar y soy principiante, por lo que tengo muchas dudas. He conseguido crear mi primer programa, pero me da el siguiente error: **f cannot be resolved to a variable, c cannot be resolved to a variable** Me imagino que sea un fallo tonto, pero estaría muy agradecido si alguien me pudiese ayudar. Aquí el código:

```
public class Celsius {
    // Atributos de mi clase Celsius
    public double tempF, tempC, c, f;
    // Metodos para poner la tempertura
    public void setF(double f) {
        tempF = f;
    }
    public void setC(double c) {
        tempC = c;
    }
    // Otros dos métodos para llamar al objeto y que nos transforme las variables f y c
    public double celsiusToFarenheit() {
        return (1.8*tempC)+32;
    }
    public double farenheitToCelsius() {
        return (tempF-32)/1.8;
    }

    public double getF() {
        return this.f;
    }

    public double getC() {
        return this.c;
    }
}
```

La segunda parte del código, donde me da el error:

```
public class PruebaTemperatura {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Celsius Prueba1 = new Celsius(); // Objeto de Prueba número 1
        Prueba1.setF(100); // LLamada al método setF, se establece la variable f
        Prueba1.setC(20); // LLamada al método setC, se establece la variable c
        System.out.println(Prueba1.getF() + " grados farenheit son " + Prueba1.farenheitToCelsius() + " grados celsius.");
        System.out.println(Prueba1.getC() + " grados Celsius son " + Prueba1.celsiusToFarenheit() + " grados Farenheit");
    }
}
```

Comment: Las variables `f` y `c` que usas en `System.out.println()` no están definidas en ese contexto. Por otra parte, las variables `c`  y `f` que declaras en la clase `Celsius`  están de más, no las usas para nada, por lo que puedes eliminarlas sin ningún problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro, porque las variables 'f' y 'c' están definidas en la clase Celsius, no en la clase PruebaTemperatura. Podrías hacerte los metodos get de estas variables en la clase Celsius y luego con Prueba1.getF() o Prueba1.getC() recuperas el valor de las variables.
Saludos

```
public class Celsius {
    // Atributos de mi clase Celsius
    public double tempF, tempC, c, f;
    // Metodos para poner la tempertura
    public void setF(double f) {
        tempF = f;
    }
    public void setC(double c) {
        tempC = c;
    }
    // Otros dos métodos para llamar al objeto y que nos transforme las variables f y c
    public double celsiusToFarenheit() {
        return (1.8*tempC)+32;
    }
    public double farenheitToCelsius() {
        return (tempF-32)/1.8;
    }

    public double getF() {
        return this.f;
    }

    public double getC() {
        return this.c;
    }
}
```

La segunda parte del código, donde me da el error:

```
public class PruebaTemperatura {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Celsius Prueba1 = new Celsius(); // Objeto de Prueba número 1
        Prueba1.setF(100); // LLamada al método setF, se establece la variable f
        Prueba1.setC(20); // LLamada al método setC, se establece la variable c
        System.out.println(Prueba1.getF() + " grados farenheit son " + Prueba1.farenheitToCelsius() + " grados celsius.");
        System.out.println(Prueba1.getC() + " grados Celsius son " + Prueba1.celsiusToFarenheit() + " grados Farenheit");
    }
}
```

Comment: Señalar también que `c` y `f` están de más en la clase `Celsius`, lo digo por si OP tiene confusión entre lo que se recibe en parámetro en los *setter* y esas variables. La clase puede declarar solamente esto: `public double tempF, tempC;` sin más.